# How to sort the List of object having a map based on the map key -> object property in java?

Tags: java, spring, collections

I have a list of objects (FolioDto) which looks like this

```
public class FoliosDto implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5307750871230L;

  private Map<String, ActionDto> folioConfig = new HashMap(); 
}
```

And ActionDto looks like below:

```
public class ActionDto {
  private Boolean isAllowed;
  private String remark;
}
```

and i have `List<FolioDto>` folios, i want to sort the folios on the basis of `folioDto.getfolioConfig().isAllowed` field where all the FolioDto which is having isAllowed as true should come first.

Tried this:

```
Collections.sort(folios, new Comparator<FoliosDto>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FoliosDto holding1, FoliosDto holding2) {
            Map<String, Object> folioConfig1 = holding1.getFolioConfig();
            Map<String, Object> folioConfig2 = holding2.getFolioConfig();
            ActionDto schemeActionDto1 = (ActionDto) folioConfig1.get("key1");
            SchemeActionDto schemeActionDto2 = (ActionDto) folioConfig2.get("key1"));
            return -1 * Boolean.compare(schemeActionDto1.getIsAllowed(), schemeActionDto2.getIsAllowed());
        }
    });
```

But this does not work and not sorting the List of objects.

I am not able to figure out, pls suggest some idea

Comment: I would use `Comparator.comparing(...).reversed()` and just provide the code to extract the boolean from `FoliosDto` to `comparing(...)`. Makes it way cleaner to read. So it might be something like `Comparator.comparing(folios -> ((ActionDto)folios.getFolioConfig().get("key1")).getIsAllowed()).reversed()`. If that doesn't work then you might want to check if value extraction works and returns the values you want (i.e. you might get ' FALSE'  when not expecting this, you might get `null` is there's no value for `"key1"` etc.)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Thomas, How can i pass folios to comparing ? ```        Collections.sort(folios, Comparator.comparing(folios -> ((ActionDto)folios.getFolioConfig().get("key1")).getIsAllowed()).reversed());
```

Comment: The last snippet I provided is called a lambda function, i.e. `folios` is the name of the parameter it would get. Just define that comparator and pass it to `Collections.sort(folios, theComparator)`. Now that I'm reading that code again, you might need to rename `folios` inside the lambda to something else (e.g. `foliosDto` or so) because it might conflict with the list named `folios`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured by myself out as below.

```
    private void sortFolios(List<HoldingFoliosDto> folios) {
        Collections.sort(folios, sortingByIsAllowedRedeem.reversed());
    }

    public Comparator<HoldingFoliosDto> sortingByIsAllowedRedeem = (dto1, dto2) -> {
        Map<String, Object> folioConfig1 = dto1.getFolioConfig();
        Map<String, Object> folioConfig2 = dto2.getFolioConfig();
        SchemeActionDto schemeActionDto1 = (SchemeActionDto) folioConfig1.get("key1");
        SchemeActionDto schemeActionDto2 = (SchemeActionDto) folioConfig2.get("key1");
        return Boolean.compare(schemeActionDto1.getIsAllowed(), schemeActionDto2.getIsAllowed());
    };
```